# Can we have session names as query string to store sessions?

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
if (Session[Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()] == null)
{
    Session[Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()] = adRepo.GetPostById(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]));
}
dt = (DataTable)Session[Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()];
```

is it the suggested thing to do?
I know the session count will go on enormously. But is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you cannot use a query string variable as a session key but as Simon pointed out this MAY be a candidate for caching.

What are you trying to accomplish with this? From your example it looks like you're passing around an ID for a post of some sort and then storing the data table that represents that post in session by the post ID. Are you clearing out the session variable? How much data is in the data table? Is this something that other users may want/need to access? What will the user do with the information in the data table? Even if it's not a candidate for caching, if the user is accessing multiple posts you're going to have a lot of garbage clogging up your session very quickly if you're not careful. How heavy is the query? Would SQL server caching be an option here?

A little more information would go a long way towards a good solution.

Comment: Eventhough simon suggested the alternative. Besides that you made me to realize which thing needs to be adapted for what. Actually the query retrieves only one row of data with a table of 15 columns. and any user is free to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

The object you are trying to cache will only be available for the visitors. What if another visitor request the same object? You will cache it 2 times.

It's better to use the built in cache function you can use features like cache experions time and timeslideing. Or just save it in the HttpApplication so the object will be global.

But I would recomend the cache see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx